# Prevent from UIAlertView to repeat when click on tableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I'm kinda stuck with a stupid problem, in my app when a user press on a `TableViewCell` he can change some value in the server, before i am sending the information to server i want to show `UIAlertView` to the user to make sure he wants to do that.

so in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

i wrote this

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Caution!" message:@"bla bla " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
```

then its calls the `UIAlertView` method `clickedButtonAtIndex:`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSString *url = @"some url";
            NSDictionary *paramerter = @{@"parameter":parameter};
            [self.jsonHandler startParseWithParameters:paramerter andUrlAdress:url withCompletion:^(int errValue) {
                if (errValue == 1) {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR");

                }else if (errValue == 0){

                    [self AlertViewWithTitle:@"success" andMessage:@"success"];

                }
            }];
    }

}
```

the problem is that the `if (buttonIndex == 0)` called for every cell and change them all!
and i get `UIAlertView` message for every cell in the tableView.

how can i prevent it?

**EDIT**
Ok the problem caused because i use the same buttonIndex for both UIAlertViews 
i solved it using this:

```
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"buttonString"]){

       //Do what ever you need

}
```

hope someone find it helpful.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. You select a cell and that displays an alert view. correct? Then you tap a button on the alert and your alert delegate method is called, correct? What do you mean the `if (buttonIndex == 0)` is called for every cell? Your code is written to show the alert for each cell that is tapped. Is that not what you want? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry.. i'm now see that the if (buttonIndex == 0) not called for every cell. its just stuck on it in loop and show the UIAlertView many times!

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy. Reading your comment and still I don't understand what you really want. Please update your question with more details

Comment: i think i figure out the problem. maybe because is the second AlertView i'm pressing OK its call the if (buttonIndex == 0) again.. should i use tag?

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that you are unable to differentiate between different alerts that have the same delegate. If that is the question, then yes, using a `tag` should work fine.